# List the contents of all subdirectories of the current directory - parse ls vs. globbing

Tags: shell

In the book "Beginning Portable Shell Scripting" by Peter Seebach there is an example how to list the contents of all subdirectories of the current directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/ls | while read file
do
  if test -d "$file"; then
   ( cd "$file" && ls )
  fi
done
```

I learned that parsing ls is bad and globbing should be prefered. Do you think the author chooses parsing because there is a portability issue?

I would do:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in *
do
 if test -d "$file"; then
  ( cd "$file" && ls )
 fi
done
```

Thanks,

Somebody

Answer (score 3):

Both solutions are not robust against weird filenames, nor do they handle directories which begin with ".". I would write this using find, e.g.:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ls '{}' ';'`

but first I'd question what output is actually required, either for a person to eyeball or a further script to digest.

You'll probably be able to do in a single "find" what is going to cost a lot of process forks with the for/while ... do ... done loop.

Comment: You may want to use `+` instead of `';'`.  Also, `-maxdepth` is specific to GNU find.

Answer (score 2):

[Globbing is much preferred over parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) since it will handle filenames that include spaces and other characters.

For the specific case in your question, you may be able to use nothing more than:

```
ls */
```

Comment: Agreed, although I much prefer the solution using `find` to even get rid of the `for` loop.

Comment: In this case, the use of ls will handle filenames that include spaces and other characters. The only character that would be a problem is a newline.